# read from XML or api into android

Tags: android

Hi
I need to make an application for android that will display current weather and weather forcast for any city. I know google has an api for that.
While searching in the web I found some website that has exactly what i am looking for.
They provide the code. BUT they dont have any step by step tutorial. What I am looking for is a tutorial which explains in details so that i can understand the basics.
Can anybody plz suggest me such tutorial?? would be a great help for me.

cheers

Answer (score 0):

You can use webservice for that.some of websites providing it.for this they provide xml or rss file.you have to pass parameter just like city or country name and you have given data accoring it.you have to than parse it .this is the best link that i have used for that:http://www.google.com/ig/api?weather=ahmedabad

---

you have to give only city as parameter and than you have to parse data according to it.just put any city as i put ahmedabad